# When installing modules in Nginx, an error like ‘ENGINE_by_id’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0

Tags: nginx

**Preface**

- Ubuntu 22.04 running in VirtualBox
- Connected to it via ssh from the host Ubuntu 22.04
- OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)

**Playback Steps**:

- Installed NGINX 1.21.0 mainline [from here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/#source-releases:%7E:text=the%20development%20branch.-,Source%20Releases%C2%B6,-There%20are%20currently)
- Go to the installed directory `cd nginx-1.21.0/`.
- Install dependencies  `sudo apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev libpcrecpp0v5:i386 libssl-dev`.
- Specify the modules we want to include in the installation `./configure --sbin-path=/usr/bin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --with-debug --with-pcre --with-http_ssl_module`
  The list of modules is listed
  [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/installoptions/#files-and-permissions).
- `sudo make install`

**Expected Result**:

- Module installation completes successfully

**Factual result**:
https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#4959aac0m09jeo3n4m6uo

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that some declarations were deprecated. It seems that this was just written about [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/11642)

You can use the `-Wno-error=deprecated-declarations` compilation flag to ignore warnings about deprecated OpenSSL functions and finalize the Nginx configuration.
This flag tells the compiler to ignore warnings and not convert them to errors. I realize that this is a temporary fix and may cause problems in the future, but my goal is to practice building nginx, so I'll ignore it for now.

To summarize, instead of configuring from my replay steps, I specified this:

```
./configure --sbin-path=/usr/bin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --with-debug --with-pcre --with-http_ssl_module --with-openssl-opt="no-deprecated"
make CFLAGS="-Wno-error=deprecated-declarations"
make install
```